# decrease initial delay for line-up/line-down movement

Tags: motion

so every time I press `C-n` or `C-p` for moving the point up and down and keep pressing `n` or `p` I move several lines. However, after the first line move, there is a delay before the point is moving down in a faster pace. How can I decrease this so that the movement it more rapidly?

Comment: This question is not about emacs. You should ask it in the appropriate site for your OS and/or graphical environment. If you are running X11, see the answer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199689/how-to-change-the-key-repeat-interval) question.

Comment: If you are running OSX, the option is in System Preferences, under Keyboard:  Key Repeat Rate and Delay Until Repeat.

Comment: @NickD: How do we know that this is not about Emacs?

Comment: OP: If this is about Emacs, do you see the same thing when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew: I guess we don't. I just jumped to the conclusion that this is about key repeat rate. OTOH, I'm pretty sure it's about key repeat rate :-)

Comment: same thing in vanilla emacs. I am running ubuntu 18.04